# How to make PHP perform API call while API call fails

Tags: php

I am trying to write PHP code that grabs a random verse from the Torah (Genesis, Exodus, Leviticus, Numbers, Deuteronomy) and displays the verse. If it randomly selects a verse that does not exist, I receive the JSON data "error:" "$book ends at $chapter."

However, when I include the below while loop, it seems to be completely ignored by the code. I can see from another part of my code that it has selected a verse which does not exist, but did not change it. Is there any way to render the following logic in PHP?

while $data contains string 'ends at' -> set book, chapter, verse to random -> make api call and assign to variable $data

```
while (strpos($data, 'ends at')) {

$bookNum = rand(1,5);

if ($bookNum == 1) {
    $book = 'Genesis';
}
elseif ($bookNum == 2) {
    $book = 'Exodus';
}
elseif ($bookNum == 3) {
    $book = 'Leviticus';
}
elseif ($bookNum == 4) {
    $book = 'Numbers';
}
elseif ($bookNum == 5) {
    $book = 'Deuteronomy';
}

$chapter = rand(1,50);

$chapter = strval($chapter);

$verse = rand(1,89);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.sefaria.org/api/texts/${book}.${chapter}.$verse");

$data = curl_exec($ch);

}
```

edit: It actually seems that the code is choosing a non-existent verse, choosing another non-existent verse, then stopping.

For example, refer to the below:

{"error": "Exodus ends at Chapter 40."}Genesis 18:37

Comment: Letting aside other issues: use a `switch` statement, that's what they are made for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the entry on `curl_exec` in the PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) the function returns a boolean value unless called with a specific option:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

Have you set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option?

---

**edit**
Just saw your edit – the second one doesn't look like an error though, does it? It looks more like your server is not giving you the *content* of the chapter but only its title – or you might be accessing the wrong part of the JSON response?

Be it as it may, might I suggest a slight change of approach? I'd personally get rid of the while loop. Pick a book at random and stick with it, make your first call to a random chapter. If it exists (no error in the response data) – hey presto. If it doesn't, use the number returned (let's call it `$maxChapters`) in the error message to pick a new chapter at random: Exodus ends at chapter 40, so `$maxChapters = 40;` so `$chapter = rand(1, $maxChapters);` will guarantee a hit. That way you'll get a valid chapter in no more than two calls to your server. A simple regex can extract you `$maxChapters` from the error message.

Simplified, the code might look like this:

```php
$bookNames = [
 1 => 'Genesis',
 2 => 'Exodus',
 3 => 'Leviticus',
 4 => 'Numbers',
 5 => 'Deuteronomy',
];

$bookNum = rand(1,5);
$book = $bookNames[$bookNum];
$chapter = rand(1,50);
$chapter = strval($chapter);

$verse = rand(1,89);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.sefaria.org/api/texts/${book}.${chapter}.$verse");

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$parsedData = json_parse($data)

if (isset($data->error) && strpos($data->error, 'ends at')) {
  preg_match(/.* ends at .* ([0-9]*)/, $data['error'], $parsedError);
  $maxChapters = $parsedError[1];
  $chapter = rand(1, $maxChapters);
  // --> initiate new request which will have a valid result this time
} else {
  // here's a valid result
  return $data;
}
```

---

**edit 2**
So I took another look at the API you're using, and the last part of your query (the verse) does not seem to do anything, so you may as well leave it out?
You get the text content of your chapter using `$chapter = $parsedData->text`, which will in turn be an array of verses. You could then do

```php
while (!isset($chapter[$verse]) {
  $verse = $verse = rand(1,89);
}
$result = $chapter[$verse];
```

Answer (score 1):

If problem is only number of chapter you should predefine maximum number of chapters for each book. That will avoid you to execute unnecessary additional calls.

It's more likely that error message will change that the size of chapters, so you should not rely on a comparing strings. Additionally you should implement error handling if you didn't get any result.

```
$books = [
    1 => [
        'name' => 'Genesis',
        'size' => 50
    ],
    2 => [
        'name' => 'Exodus',
        'size' => 40
    ],
    3 => [
        'name' => 'Leviticus',
        'size' => 27
    ],
    4 => [
        'name' => 'Numbers',
        'size' => 36
    ],
    5 => [
        'name' => 'Deuteronomy',
        'size' => 34
    ],
];

$bookNum = rand(1, 5);

$book = $books[$bookNum]['name'];

$chapter = strval(rand(1, $books[$bookNum]['size']));

$verse = rand(1, 89);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.sefaria.org/api/texts/${book}.${chapter}.$verse");

$data = curl_exec($ch);
```